# How to get the page title from Wikipedia page URL?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, wikipedia

I'm trying to create a system where the user will input their Wikipedia page link, and the application will get the page title from Wikipedia page URL.

Like, if the user gives: `https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminem`, I want to get the page title `Eminem`.

Or if the user gives: `https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminem#1992%E2%80%931997:_Awal_karier,_Infinite_dan_masalah_keluarga`, I want the page title, which is `Eminem`

I've tried finding a  **regex** pattern. I'm thinking about what if I could create/ find a regex pattern that would find words that sit between `/wiki/` and ends with a `/`. So far didn't found any way to do that.

So what can I do? What other options I have?

Comment: Why not make a request for the Wikipedia page to get the title from the rendered HTML - or use Wikipedia's web-service? https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/

Comment: @Dai Any idea on how I do this via the Wikipedia API?

Comment: Thanks to `moddy
#8459` - discord, for helping me on this

Comment: I know this post is closed but here's an example I put together that should work.
/https?:\/\/?.*\.wikipedia\.org\/wiki\/([^\/|#|\?]+).*/

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, as I think it is a perfectly valid and clear use case (disclaimer: I'm a sysop and script developer on Wikipedia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would partly work: `/(?<=https?:\/\/..\.wikipedia\.org\/wiki\/).+(?=\/(.+)?|#)/`
It doesn't work without a / at the end though.

Comment: You could dynamically add `/` at the end once you receive the input URL